# A proof using the integration of power series and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, power-series

Define $f(x) = \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots +\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n -1)!}+ \dots$ and $g(x) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots +\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+ \dots$ on $\mathbb R.$ Prove that for all $x \in \mathbb R$:

1. $1 + \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = g(x)$.
2. $\int_{0}^{x} g(t) dt = f(x).$

**My thoughts are:**

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus together with integration of power series. But I have a problem in applying the fundamental theorem of calculus though. Could someone show me the details please?By the way, I have seen a solution that did not use the fundamental theorem of calculus at all, so maybe I am wrong in this thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those power series have an infinite radius of convergences and you can deal with them as if they were polynomials. To be more precise: their convergence is uniform on any bounded interval, and therefore exchanging infinite sums and integrals, as I do below, is allowable. You have\begin{align}1+\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt&=1+\int_0^x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\,\mathrm dt\\&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^x\frac{t^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\,\mathrm dt\\&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\&=g(x).\end{align}The other equality is similar.

Comment: But you used the fundamental theorem of calculus on your third equality, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I did.${}$